# Reloading to homepage after hitting an empty anchor

Tags: php, jquery, menu, content-management-system, modx

Please have a look at http://iglica.dbox.pl/modx/ (clients graphical project)

Check "KURSY" on the menu - on the homepage everything is okay, the menu slides, I can pick something from the sub-menu, etc. Somehow, when I click on "KURSY" from every other place, MODX redirects me to the homepage.

The code responsible for the menu is in menu.min.js (I`ve bought it specially for this website - I'm not a jQuery familiar).

P.S.

I've tried this http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Named+Anchor with no luck

P.S.

jQuery -

```
$(function () {
    $('#mainNav ul li.slide a').click(function () {
        var content = ($(this).parent().find("div").html());
        $('#navWrapper #subNav #subNavContainer').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $('#navWrapper #subNav #subNavContainer').html(content);
            $('#navWrapper #subNav #subNavContainer').fadeIn(100);
            $('#navWrapper').stop(false, false).animate({
                'left': 0
            }, 300)
        })
    });
    $('#navWrapper').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#navWrapper').stop(false, false).animate({
            'left': -200
        }, 300)
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace the a tags which you don't want to do anything with span tags and see if your js code still works fine. Maybe you have to look at your css styles afterwards.

```
<li class="slide"><span>Kursy</span>
<div class="submenu">
<ul id="submenu">
<li><a href="index.php?id=12">Dla dzieci</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=23">Dla młodzieży</a></li>
<li><a href="index.php?id=13">Dla dorosłych</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
```

Ok, when slide functions are triggered by anchor may try a js workaround:

**HTML**

```
<li class="slide"><a href="#" class="preventdefault">Kursy</a>
    <div class="submenu">
    <ul id="submenu">
    <li><a href="index.php?id=12">Dla dzieci</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=23">Dla młodzieży</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.php?id=13">Dla dorosłych</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</li>
```

**JS**

```
(function ($) {
    $(window).ready(function () {
        $('.preventdefault').on("click", function (e) {
            //Uncomment if the anchor is required on the url
            //document.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

            return false;
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

**Your code extended + adding html class:**

```
$(function () {
    $('#mainNav ul li.slide a').click(function (e) {
        var content = ($(this).parent().find("div").html());
        $('#navWrapper #subNav #subNavContainer').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $('#navWrapper #subNav #subNavContainer').html(content);
            $('#navWrapper #subNav #subNavContainer').fadeIn(100);
            $('#navWrapper').stop(false, false).animate({
                'left': 0
            }, 300)
        })

        if ($(this).hasClass('preventdefault')) {
            //Uncomment if the anchor is required on the url
            //document.location.hash = $(this).attr('href');

            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }

    });
    $('#navWrapper').mouseleave(function () {
        $('#navWrapper').stop(false, false).animate({
            'left': -200
        }, 300)
    })
});
```

Comment: Slide functionality is trigerred by anchor

Comment: After seen your code example at your start post, functionality is not triggered by anchor, but the click is binded on the a tag.

Comment: I`ve used your code but problem still occurs. I think this is a 100% modx issue (being on a subpage and hover over "kursy" it show something like this http://iglica.dbox.pl/modx/# - apparently modx interprets it as "go to # tag inside homepage" and reloads).

Comment: It is because your a href links to # what effects that your page is reloaded and then modx takes # for startpage. what i've tried is to prevent the default link functions so the page doesnt gets reloaded.

Comment: Yes!!! It works!!! (I`ve made some mistake copying your code). I love you! I was asking for help a guy who wrote this code (I`ve paid him for it at start) for a week!!! You've helped me in 30 minutes, amazing. Once again, THANK YOU!

Comment: Glad to help you, next time better pay me :)

Comment: Haha! Paying in Euros could be hard for my wallet (in polish zlotys). As a favor I can help you only with some graphic/branding topics (maybe in future you will need some help on this field, you'd never know). Heres my portfolio http://krzysztofbalana.pl - feel free to ask if you have any questions. Best regards, Chriss.

Comment: No prob, but pls mark the answer as accepted and vote up, so other visitors can se it was helpful.